# Underline shift

Tags: vertical-alignment, underline

How can i prevent downshift with mixing `\underset` and `\underline`?
My code:

```
\underset{\text{должность}}
{\underline{\hspace{1cm}\text{доцент, к.т.н.}\hspace{1cm}}}
\quad\underset{\text{подпись, дата}}{\underline{\hspace{4cm}}}
\quad\underset{\text{инициалы, фамилия}}{\underline{\hspace{1cm}\text{Е.А. Коренева}\hspace{1cm}}}
```

How it looks now:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that the content has the same height. To ensure this, you can add `\strut`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \underset{\text{Text on left}}
    {\underline{\hspace{1cm}\text{\strut Quick brown fox}\hspace{1cm}}}
  \quad\underset{\text{Text in middle}}{\underline{\strut\hspace{4cm}}}
  \quad\underset{\text{Text on right}}
    {\underline{\hspace{1cm}\text{\strut Lazy dog}\hspace{1cm}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, you could achieve something similar using `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ C{10em} *{2}{ c C{10em} } }
    Quick brown fox & & & & Lazy dog \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
    \footnotesize Text on left & &
    \footnotesize Text in middle & &
    \footnotesize Text on right
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```